# MVC 3 White space removal (most optimal alogritm)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, optimization, whitespace, action-filter

Right now i am using this WhiteSpace module from Mads Kristensen, http://madskristensen.net/post/A-whitespace-removal-HTTP-module-for-ASPNET-20.aspx

Its working "ok" but it could be better (The output that i get could be reduced further from whitespaces). Does anyone have a good regex/algoritm to remove whitespaces? I mean, like the one google.com uses. Now thats efficient.

The only criteria that i have is that you can use it from inside and a MVC action filter.

Comment: You have an code example to illustrate the situation? And what text do you want to remove the whitespaces from?

Comment: Lets make an example. I got a View that renders a table with 100 elements on it. I then want to remove all the whitespaces between the tags upon output (this is already compressed). Go to google.com and view the source code. Basicly you will find no whitespaces between the tags. Mads code works the same way but not as effective as google has made it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may [checkout HTML Tidy](http://blog.aquabirdconsulting.com/?p=61). But remember that you will get much more benefit from [compressing](http://www.58bits.com/blog/2009/05/02/GZip-And-Deflate-Compression-Filter-For-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) the [output](http://www.avantprime.com/articles/view-article/7/compress-httpresponse-for-your-controller-actions-using-attributes) rather than tidying. Just [watch for a caveat](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats) when doing this.

Comment: Also HTML Tidy, last build was 6 years ago, only cleans the code but the structure remains. I want to actually remove all the whitespace between the html-tags. Go to google.com and view the source code. Basicly you will find no whitespaces between the tags.